# SuiteScript - Search joining "Term" from "Vendor"

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am doing a search of vendors and want to join in the Term to have the Term's name. The vendor has a field called `terms` which has the `internalid` of the Term. Term has a field called `name` which contains what I'm looking for.

I've tried just about every combination of building the column but I always get an error:

`An nlobjSearchColumn contains an invalid column join ID, or is not in proper syntax: name.`

Example of how I'm building the column:

```
search.createColumn({
name: "name",
join: "terms", // or Term, or Terms, none of it works
label: "termname" // or leave this out or Term or Terms or anything else nothing works
}
```

What is the right way to create a search for `vendor` that also includes the term's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll look at the Records Browser, `terms` is not listed as a join on the vendor record. Just get `terms` as a column (`name: 'terms'`) then when you retrieve the result, use `getText` instead of `getValue`.

```
searchResults[i].getText({
    name: 'terms'
});
```